# Updating PowerBI embedded report Connection String does not work

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

So the issue is as follows : we have multiple tenants, multiple databases hosted on different Azure sql hosts with different Workspaces for every tenant. Since the number of tenants is pretty big, it's not very feasible to generate a report for every tenant and then upload it to the corresponding app workspace. So we've tried to automate the whole process, based on some configs.(We have the same report for every tenant, only the data source is different). We managed to upload the same report to the corresponding app workspace, but we can't manage to programatically update the ConnectionString. It seems to be failing when we try to change the Data Source. The uploaded file retains it's original ConnectionString. Also the report is set up using DirectQuery.

Sample code:

```
var import = await pbiClient.Imports.PostImportWithFileAsyncInGroup(GroupId, fileStream, importName, nameConflict);//Name conflicts : Abort, Ignore, Overwrite

var datasets = await pbiClient.Datasets.GetDatasetsInGroupAsync(GroupId);
var latestDataset = datasets.Value.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == importName);

var reports = await pbiClient.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync(GroupId);
var latestReport = reports.Value.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == importName);

var connectionDetails = new ConnectionDetails($"Data Source={DbHost} ;Initial Catalog={DbName};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;PersistSecurityInfo=True;User Id={DbPowerBIUser};Password={DbPowerBIUser};MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
var resp = await pbiClient.Datasets.SetAllDatasetConnectionsInGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync(GroupId, latestDataset.Id, connectionDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to poll on the import status, until it's successfully completed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/imports/getimportbyidingroup
2. When you're setting the new connection, the username and password in the connection string are ignored (you can set them if needed using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways/updatedatasource)
3. What do you mean seems to be failing? Do you get an exception from the api call? Or the report is rendering with the old data?

Comment: 1. I am not doing this, but i will try, imports actually appear in app.powerbi.com
2. I am not using a gateway for the datasource, maybe that's the problem
3. seems to be failing as in i log in to app.powerbi.com and i click on the report and it points me to the file's old datasource

Comment: It takes up to 30 minutes for the change of the ConnectionString to be effective.